# How to create custom control that focusable and can handle input?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, custom-controls

I want to create custom control which will be inherited from Control and make it focusable and able to handle input from keyboard. I managed to create control and draw border, background and text on it, but can't make it to be focusable on tab or mouse click like textbox and handle keyboard input in OnKeyPress event.

My code

```
    public class newTextEdit : Control
    {
        private string str = "this is text";
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Point startingPoint = new Point(0, 0);
            StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
            Font font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily.Name, this.Font.Size, FontStyle.Italic);
            if (this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
            {
                format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 1, 1, this.Width - 2, this.Height - 2);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("this is text", font, Brushes.Gray, this.ClientRectangle, format);
        }

        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            str += e.KeyChar;
        }
    }
```

Created control in right bottom corner:

[image: Created control in right bottom corner]

Comment: Is TabStop set to true in Behaviour section of properties window?

Comment: I just tested your code and it works as expected.  Keypress works when the control is focused.  There is nothing to indicate it is focused though, maybe that is why you think it is not focused.  Change the border color or something on focus and you will see.

Comment: The Control class sets `ControlStyles.Selectable` and `ControlStyles.StandardClick` (among the others), so it's already *selectable*. You could add `ControlStyles.UserMouse`. -- In OnPaint, you're drawing a fixed string instead of `str`. ++ After `str += e.KeyChar;`, you need to `Invalidate()` the Control. +++ You don't need to fill a rectangle with Color.White, just the the BackColor. +++ The Font must not be defined in `OnPaint`. +++ To draw a Border, use `ControlPaint.DrawBorder()`. To check whether the Control is focused, check `this.ContainsFocus`. Also `ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle()`

Comment: @hijinxbassist thanks! I forgot to put str into DrawString and didn't notice that OnKeyPress was working. And I thought that on mouse click it should focus automatically, but now I'm not sure. Calling Focus() in OnMouseClick event now.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you too!